# How to summarize (with multiple outputs) a column in a dataset by groups efficiently?

Tags: r, dplyr, purrr

Often times, I need to provide summary statistics (mean, sd, median, Q1 etc.) to a variable by groups.

Currently I am using code like,

```
data %>%
  group_by(region, group) %>%
  summarise(mean=mean(value),
            sd=sd(value),
            min=min(value),
            q1 = quantile(value, probs=0.25),
            median = median(value),
            q3 = quantile(value, probs=0.75),
            max=max(value))
```

I found myself repeat this practice a lot. Is there a better way to get the same summary table? Thanks.

Comment: Write a function that does exactly that. `function(data, column) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @January suggested in the comments, creating a function is a good idea. Here I used `quos` to quote each argument of `...` and splice them into `group_by` using `!!!`. `enquo` is used to convert the expression into a quosure. `!!` then unquotes it within the context of each summary function:

```
library(dplyr)
library(rlang)

summary_stats1 <- function(data, value, ...){
  value <- enquo(value)

  data %>%
    group_by(!!!quos(...)) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(!!value),
              sd=sd(!!value),
              min=min(!!value),
              q1 = quantile(!!value, probs=0.25),
              median = median(!!value),
              q3 = quantile(!!value, probs=0.75),
              max=max(!!value))
}
```

Alternatively, use `group_by_at`. Which accepts the `vars` helper function, taking `...` directly:

```
summary_stats2 <- function(data, value, ...){
  value <- enquo(value)

  data %>%
    group_by_at(vars(...)) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean(!!value),
              sd=sd(!!value),
              min=min(!!value),
              q1 = quantile(!!value, probs=0.25),
              median = median(!!value),
              q3 = quantile(!!value, probs=0.75),
              max=max(!!value))
}
```

We can also use the new interpolation pattern (rlang 0.4.0), described [here](https://www.tidyverse.org/articles/2019/06/rlang-0-4-0/) to simplify the quote and unquote process:

```
summary_stats3 <- function(data, value, ...){

  data %>%
    group_by_at(vars(...)) %>%
    summarise(mean=mean({{ value }}),
              sd=sd({{ value }}),
              min=min({{ value }}),
              q1 = quantile({{ value }}, probs=0.25),
              median = median({{ value }}),
              q3 = quantile({{ value }}, probs=0.75),
              max=max({{ value }}))
}
```

**Output:**

```
> summary_stats1(mtcars, mpg, gear, am)
> summary_stats2(mtcars, mpg, gear, am)
> summary_stats3(mtcars, mpg, gear, am)

# A tibble: 4 x 9
# Groups:   gear [3]
   gear    am  mean    sd   min    q1 median    q3   max
  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     3     0  16.1  3.37  10.4  14.5   15.5  18.4  21.5
2     4     0  21.0  3.07  17.8  18.8   21    23.2  24.4
3     4     1  26.3  5.41  21    21.3   25.0  30.9  33.9
4     5     1  21.4  6.66  15    15.8   19.7  26    30.4
```